# Create archive to include same filenames from different paths in Windows powershell

Tags: powershell, path, filenames, archive

I require to create powershell script for `yello.zip` archive by searching inside `$workspace` and including comma separate files mentioned in `$itemsToInclude`

There should be a single copy of all files but in case of the `deployfiles` folder it should include multiple files having the same filenames inside the deployfiles folder.

Thus, the following files are expected to be seen in the archive.

```
C:\Temp\appone\ROOT.war
C:\Temp\appone\DEV\deployfiles\file1.xls
C:\Temp\appone\UAT\deployfiles\file1.xls
C:\Temp\appone\deployfiles\DEV\file2.xls
C:\Temp\appone\deployfiles\UAT\file2.xls
```

Powershell:

```
$workspace = "C:\Temp\appone"

$zipFileName = "$workspace\yello.zip"

$tempZipFileName = "$workspace\temp.zip"

cd $workspace

$itemsToInclude = "ROOT.war,deployfiles"

Write-Host "itemsToInclude is- $itemsToInclude"

 

if ($itemsToInclude -eq '*') {

    # Include all files, including files from subdirectories

    Write-Host "Include all files, including files from subdirectories"

    Get-ChildItem -Path $workspace -Recurse -File |

        Compress-Archive -DestinationPath $tempZipFileName -Force

} else {

    # Include specific files as per the comma-separated list

    Write-Host "Include specific files as per the comma-separated list"

    $pattern = $itemsToInclude.Split(',').ForEach({ [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

    Get-ChildItem $workspace -Recurse -File |

        Where-Object FullName -Match $pattern |

        ForEach-Object {

            $relativePath = $_.FullName.Replace($workspace, "")

            $relativePath = $relativePath -replace "^\\", "" # Remove leading backslash

            $destinationPath = Join-Path -Path $tempZipFileName -ChildPath $relativePath

            $destinationFolder = Split-Path -Path $destinationPath

            if (-not (Test-Path -Path $destinationFolder)) {

                New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationFolder | Out-Null

            }

            Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destinationPath -Force

        }

    Compress-Archive -Path $tempZipFileName -DestinationPath $zipFileName -Update

}
```

The above creates temp.zip recursively and never completes execution. See output below:

[image]

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What is wrong with the current code?

Comment: It creates temp.zip folder inside yello.zip @jdweng

Comment: It seems to create temp.zip recursively in `$workspace` folder as well as inside yello.zip  which is not needed @jdweng –

Comment: @jdweng updated the original post with the recursive folder creation issue.

Comment: Why do you need a temp folder.  Try this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-7.4#example-6-use-the-pipeline-to-archive-files

Comment: @jdweng for my version of powershell the `-Update` option does not work:

Compress-Archive : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At C:\Logs\getallkey.ps1:24 char:9
+         Compress-Archive -Path $_.FullName -Update -DestinationPath $ ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Compress-Archive], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Compress-Archive

Comment: If you are piping the file names than you do not need -Path.  Error is indicating you have input filenames from two places 1) The Pipe 2) -Path  You do not need both.